# Algorithm: Compressing symbols into bitstrings by expected frequencies?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression

I have a table of 1 million symbols and their expected frequency.

I would like to compress sequences of these symbols by assigning each symbol a unique (and prefix unique) variable length bit string, and then concatenating these together to represent the sequence.

I would like to assign these bitstrings such that the expected bit length of an encoded sequence is minimized.

For example if the symbols and expected frequencies were:

```
foo 0.5
bar 0.25
baz 0.25
```

Than one of the best encodings would be:

```
foo 0
bar 10
baz 11
```

So "foobarbazfoo" translates to 010110.

By what algorithm can I translate the table of expected frequencies into a best encoding scheme?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing [*entropy coding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding).  One popular and easy-to-implement option is [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), but there are others.

Comment: The reason why Huffman coding is so popular is because it's an optimal prefix code.